# When was the Google Earth API launched?

Tags: google-earth, google, google-maps-api

Do you know the date when google launched that API:
https://developers.google.com/earth/

Comment: Since 2007, though more popular is the Google Maps API v3 with Earth Mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039250/google-earth-integrated-with-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Found the announcement. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Google Earth API was [released  at the Google I/O](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2008/05/google-earth-meet-browser.html) on **May 28, 2008**. Here's an excerpt from the article announcing the release:

> Today, I'm happy to announce the release of the new Google Earth
>   Browser Plug-in, which brings the full power of Google Earth to the
>   web, embeddable within your own web site. Driven by an extensive
>   JavaScript API, you can control the camera; create lines, markers, and
>   polygons; import 3D models from the web and overlay them anywhere on
>   the planet. In fact, you can even overlay your content over different
>   planets, stars, and galaxies by toggling Sky mode, letting you build
>   3D Google Sky mashups. You can also enable 3D buildings with a single
>   line of JavaScript, attach JavaScript callbacks to mouse events, fetch
>   KML data from the web, and more. Our goal is to open up the entire
>   core of Google Earth to developers in the hopes that you'll build the
>   next great geo-based 3D application, and change (yet again) how we
>   view the world.

<strike>According to this [announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/06/world-is-your-javascript-enabled_29.html) at the Google Blog, it was launched on **June 29, 2005**.</strike>

> **The world is your JavaScript-enabled oyster**
>
> **June 29, 2005**  Posted by Bret Taylor, Google Maps Product Manager
>
> If you like Google Maps, but think you could do something better,
>   now's your chance. Check out the Google Maps API, which lets web
>   developers put Google Maps on their own sites, just like
>   housingmaps.com and chicagocrime.org. You can also reach out to other
>   API developers and the Google Maps team in the API discussion group.
>   
>   <strike>According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps), it was launched on February 8, 2005.</strike>

Comment: I think that is the date that Google Maps was launched, not the google earth API.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Finally fixed :)